# Get Nested Stored Procedure Dependencies

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have inherited a number of very large stored procedures with nested stored procedures inside. I wanted to create a stored procedure I could run to show me all the dependencies for a particular stored procedure - listing all the tables and nested stored procedures within it.

I am using the following code but this only gives me the top level dependencies and not anything from the nested stored procedures

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_ROADMAP
(
    TBL_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    TBL_TYPE VARCHAR(20),
    TBL_PARENT VARCHAR(20),
    PROCNAME VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @PARENTPROC VARCHAR(100)
SET @PARENTPROC = '[DBO].[RULE_PROC_1]' 

INSERT INTO #TEMP_ROADMAP (TBL_OBJECT_NAME,TBL_TYPE)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [OBJECT_NAME] = SCHEMA_NAME(O.[SCHEMA_ID]) + '.' + O.NAME, O.TYPE_DESC
    FROM    
        SYS.DM_SQL_REFERENCED_ENTITIES (@PARENTPROC, 'OBJECT') D
    JOIN 
        SYS.OBJECTS O ON D.REFERENCED_ID = O.[OBJECT_ID]
    WHERE 
        O.[TYPE] IN ('U', 'V', 'P', 'IF', 'FN')

   UPDATE #TEMP_ROADMAP
   SET TBL_PARENT = 'PARENT',
       PROCNAME = @PARENTPROC
   WHERE TBL_OBJECT_NAME IS NOT NULL

   SELECT * FROM #TEMP_ROADMAP

   DROP TABLE #TEMP_ROADMAP
```

Output:

```
TBL_OBJECT_NAME  TBL_TYPE               TBL_PARENT       PROCNAME
dbo.RULE_PROC_2  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE   PARENT           [DBO].[RULE_PROC_1]
dbo.TEST_TABLE_1 USER_TABLE             PARENT           [DBO].[RULE_PROC_1]
```

Can it done where I can get the tables and name of the other nested stored procedures in this parent procedure?

Comment: Here is a very nice article which will give you a very good insight on how to do it and you can manipulate the queries written in the article depending on your requirement. https://sqlsunday.com/2013/11/03/working-with-dependencies/

Comment: Which version of SQL Server.  For older versions the sp_depends system stored proc was unreliable as was the sysdepends table, however in later version (I think post 2008R2) both were considerably more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstand you but I think you need this :-

```
   EXECUTE SP_DEPENDS <PROCNAME>
```